# How to get url of a page that makes a http ajax GET request in node.js?

Tags: node.js

In node.js I have a site that serves pages from the same server. Pages can request for files on the same server using http get with ajax. However some pages are not allowed to request a file from a certain path. How can I validate this in node.js?

Also this should be in a way a user can't hack from client side. The node.js would need a way to see if the request came from a page from a certain url and if so then block it if the link it requests is in a specified folder.

Thanks

Comment: You cannot reliably tell what page a request came from.  You can look at the referrer header, but that can easily be spoofed.  If a user gets into a state where only certain things are allowed, then you should use user authentication and server side state to determine which pages a given user is allowed to access at any time.  You shouldn't be thinking about "pages making requests".  You should be thinking about authenticated users making requests.

Comment: The page is in a sandboxed iframe though. Can I just set the origin of the iframe and check that in node.js?

Comment: Please edit your question to fully describe what you're actually asking about.  Progressive discovery of the actual question makes people not want to spend time trying to figure out what your question actually is.  As I already said, there is NO reliable way (that can't be spoofed) to say what page origin a request comes from.  You can look at the referrer header, but you cannot trust it.  You need to rethink what you're doing so that requests come from authenticated users and you can use that authentication info on the server to decide what they can access.

Comment: It's really any requests coming from 'some' iframe to a particular path should be blocked. All iframe content originally come from same origin, but all iframe are sandbox.

Comment: You don't seem to understand that you CANNOT reliably tell where a request comes from.  You CANNOT.  All that info can be spoofed.  This is my third time telling you that.  Until you edit the question and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve (not your issues with an attempt at a solution), then we cannot help you break out of the wrong path and find a different solution for your actual problem.  Please describe the actual application problem, not the details of your solution that don't work.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you've setup your server like so:

```
var http = require('http');
server = http.createServer(function(req, res)
{
   ...
```

you can get the **referring** URL by accessing `req.headers.referer`

Then you'll need to check this either with a regular expression (if the allowed URLs match a pattern) or against an array of acceptable values.

**UPDATE**
Next, you could keep an array of *valid* visited URLs in a session and then check if the acceptable referring URL is actually in this list (and thus not necessarily spoofed).

Comment: Referrer can be hacked on client side

Answer (score 0):

In any node function , we have access to request and response object. Consider the following eg :

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(request, response){
       var urlPath = request.path;
       response.send("Hello"); 
});

app.listen(3000);
```